# How to stress test a gwt app

Tags: gwt, stress-testing

Did someone have succeed stressing a GWT app?

Any recommended tool?

Comment: See :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803661/gwt-load-testing-with-jmeter

Regards

Philippe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are successfully using http://loadui.org to test our GWT app. To test the GUI we input directly JSON HTTP requests to our RPC servlet. It's also useful to test SOAP/REST web services.

Comment: Do you know some text or tutorial for doing that? ;)

Comment: No, I guess I should write one :)

Comment: Could you please give a clue of how to input directly some json into loadUI. Thanks

Comment: We do not use loadUI with JSON. We used loadui to test our webservices. JSON RPC request are made thru java code.

Comment: OK, Thanks for clarifying it to me, with this info and this post ( http://www.itsolut.com/chrismusings/2010/06/26/its-tough-to-overload-our-gwt-rpc/ ) I think I can acomplish what I need.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a blog post about this topic a little while ago.

http://blog.oio.de/2011/04/19/load-testing-gwt-applications-with-selenium-2-and-gradle

There I published a [Selenium 2](http://www.seleniumhq.org) test script written in Groovy and a [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) script for the parallel execution.

But with this solution and no accessibility from the outside its quite difficult to put a heavy load on your GWT application. Except you have many free test clients available in your work/dev environment.

Answer (score 1):

http://loadstorm.com/ is a great tool which lives in the cloud and supports Javascript. Fairly powerful and easy to setup and use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but our development server is not visible to the internet, and is not up to me to make it visible.

Answer (score 1):

We use NeoLoad for our GWT load tests campaigns. They provide an easy way to describe the JSON calls in the GUI.

You should check this out [here](http://www.neotys.com/product/technologies-gwt-stress-testing.html) to see if it can help you as well!

Answer (score 0):

My Company (UBIK-INGENIERIE) distributes a commercial Apache JMeter plugin to load test GWT and GWT RPC applications.

You can easily record, variabilize and replay GWT and GWT RPC based application with standard knowledge of Apache JMeter.

See:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/load-testing-gwt-rpc-applications-with-ubik-load-pack-plugin-for-jmeter/