# gwt-rpc deserialization rpc string

Tags: java, php, gwt-rpc, deserialization

I have gwt-rpc response string, for example:

```
//OK[1,["19.04.2011 10:49"],0,5]
```

I need to deserialize it. In the best way I want to do it with php, but as I know there are no ready solutions. So, is gwt-rpc serialization algorithm is open source and I can try implement it in php?

Or may be I can to develope some java application ( as proxy ) to deserialize it and send to php?

Comment: To figure out payload see here (reference to gwt-payload-deserializer on google code):<br>
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10525534/465710