# Problem with parsing the response of GWT app

Tags: gwt, httpresponse

I want to know how to parse the response data(like bellow) of GWT app.

Sample data:

```
//OK[41,40,0,2,39,38,37,0,36,0,4,1,4,35,19,1,3,34,19,18,1,17,1,-17,33,0,710,1,0,4,0,28,12,11,0,32,31,8,7,30,19,18,1,17,1,2,16,29,0,700,1,0,4,1,28,12,11,0,27,26,8,7,25,19,18,1,17,1,-8,24,0,500,1,150,23,1,22,12,11,0,22,21,8,7,20,19,18,1,17,1,1,16,15,0,410,1,150,14,1,13,12,11,0,10,9,8,7,4,3,1,6,5,0,4,0,0,0,3,2,1,["gov.egov.erule.regs.shared.action.LoadDocumentDetailResult/3665673162","gov.egov.erule.regs.shared.models.DocumentDetailModel/1210760895","java.util.ArrayList/3821976829","","FDA-2010-P-0532","gov.egov.erule.regs.shared.models.DocketType/1323825229","gov.egov.erule.regs.shared.models.MetadataValueModel/1270413309","gov.egov.erule.regs.shared.models.MetadataModel/1441296737","Document

Subtype","doc_sub_type","SUPPORTING & RELATED MATERIALS","1","doc_type","dk_subType_v","Used to further define the type of document","gov.egov.erule.regs.shared.models.MetadataModel$UiControlType/4187881057","com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.RpcMap/3441186752","value","java.lang.String/2004016611","CP-Citizen Petition (Supporting & Related Materials)","Status","doc_status","doc_status_v","The current status of the document","Posted","Received Date","receive_date","doc_primary_dates","The date the agency received or created the document","October 04 2010, at 12:00 AM Eastern Daylight Time ","Date Posted","fr_publish_date","Date the document is posted to Regulations.gov","November 10 2010, at 12:00 AM Eastern Standard Time ","pdf","[Ljava.lang.String;/2600011424","FDA","FDA-2010-P-0532-0005","gov.egov.erule.regs.shared.models.DocumentType/2460330259","0900006480b68632","Attachment 4 - \"Information Regarding Cigarettes with Characterizing Flavors Form 3734\" - [BBK Tobacco & Foods, LLP, (Levin Ginsburg Attorneys at Law) - Citizen Petition] "],0,7]
```

Can you tell me how to deserialize the data?

I want to scrape some information from it, e.g. "Status" (in this case, shoule be "Posted")

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
import re
re.search('The current status of the document","(\w+)',your_text).group(1)
>>> 'Posted'
```

or with json

```
import json
json.loads('{"a":1,"b":2}')
>>> {u'a': 1, u'b': 2}
```

Comment: It's not a good solution.  I also see following response data:  

"Status","doc_status","PUBLIC SUBMISSIONS","1","doc_status_v","The current status of the document","gov.egov.erule.regs.shared.models.MetadataModel$UiControlType/4187881057","com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.RpcMap/3441186752","value","Posted". 

And i need to scrape many fields from it.

Comment: You need to spell out the problem better. The comment you left to the answer shows a different format. I gave you an example of how to use re module. You will have to suit it to your text pattern

Comment: Sorry, this problem can't be solved by regex. Because the data structure is not regular. I need scrape many information from it, so i want to know how to deserialize it. Thank you all the same.

Comment: Yes, the data format is JSON. But it is serialized by GWT server side app, i want to know how deserialize it correctly.  Here is a article (http://www.gdssecurity.com/l/b/2010/05/06/fuzzing-gwt-rpc-requests/) talking about how to parse the request data, but not referering the response data.

Comment: Thank you. May you didn't understand my meaning. I always use re and json (or simplejson) module. May i should remove the "Python" tag. In fact this problem has nothing to do with Python.

Comment: I have found a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712831/gwt-rpc-deserialization-rpc-string/6466103