# Web Testing tool for GWT?

Tags: java, unit-testing, gwt, testing, automated-tests

I am looking for an **open Source** Test Automation Tool for an application developed with **GWT**.
this tool should allow:

- **Scenarios recording**
- **Maintenance of scenarios (binary files, XML, ..)**
- The integration into the build tool (Ant)

I know that Selenium do that, but I'm not sure that is the only nor  the best tool to use.
If you know others automation test tools, feel free to suggest them to me.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Try Selenium 2.

See:

- http://www.carfey.com/blog/testing-gwt-apps-with-selenium-or-webdriver/

If you need to Load Test:

- [GWT load testing with jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803661/gwt-load-testing-with-jmeter)

Regards

Philippe

Comment: Selenium may be a solution, but I want to know if there are others in order to choose the most suitable for our needs :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [GWTTestCase](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/junit/client/GWTTestCase.html)? Refer [Testing Methodologies Using Google Web Toolkit](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/testing_methodologies_using_gwt) article on Google Developers better insight.

Comment: I have not tried GWTTestCase, but it seems not to meet all our needs.
Indeed, the tool should allow us to record scenarios (from a browser or proxy) and avoid hard coding of scenarios.

Comment: @user405458 If you want to avoid hand writing code, Selenium RC is a better choice. It provides record/play feature, but managing/maintaining the recordings will be a challenge as your test scenarios grow.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to commercial tools then I'd like to recommend [Telerik's Test Studio](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools). (Disclosure: I am the evangelist for that tool.)

We do a great job with creating very maintainable recorded tests, plus you've got the ability to dive in to as little or as much code as you need to flesh out your test suite. Test Studio handles load testing too. There's also a command line runner which is a perfect integration point in to Ant or any other build system. (We have our own scheduler, too, if you prefer that.)

Moreover, we do a great job with helping create solid tests in dynamic content situations -- AJAX, e.g.

Comment: Thank you Jim, it's clear that it is a complete tool. But in our society we use only open source tools ;)