# Using JMeter to load test a GWT RPC application

Tags: java, gwt, jmeter

I'm working on a  project which is developed in GWT.
Due to GWT-RPC serialization, requests/response are encoded. Could you please let me know if there is any way to do performance testing this kind of GWT application with Jmeter.

Answer (score 2):

This question has already been handled here:

- [GWT load testing with jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803661/gwt-load-testing-with-jmeter)
- http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Load-Testing-of-GWT-Application-td4841382.html

My Company (UBIK-INGENIERIE) distributes [UBIK LOAD PACK](http://www.ubikloadpack.com) a **commercial** Apache JMeter plugin to load test GWT and GWT RPC applications.

You can easily record, variabilize and replay GWT and GWT RPC based application with standard knowledge of Apache JMeter.

Comment: Can you please let me know what is cost of that plugin?