# How to encode the GWT Long value in RPC Request

Tags: java, gwt, encode, rpc

I am using JMeter to generate random number for load test

Q) How to encode the long value below "DI"? The original value is 200.

7|0|8|http://10.6.3.1:90/portal/|E5514987BAA783F640F3B2046EE770BB|com.portal.shared.Rpc|process|java.lang.String/2004016611|J|60182009111|password|1|2|3|4|3|5|6|5|7|**DI**|8|

Some solution being posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803661/gwt-load-testing-with-jmeter) but's it been more than a decade ago . Any newer solution?

Answer (score 1):

The value is base64 encoded. Use `com.google.gwt.user.server.Base64Utils.longFromBase64(long)` to create a string that represents a given value, or `Base64Utils.longFromBase64(String)` to read a string and convert it into a long value, to see what it represents.

Comment: Hi, you are close, but the value converted to long224564. Check out my answer.

Comment: Yes, you are using the client version of the code in your answer, which only works when compiled to JS. The code in my answer works from any jvm, so is usually easier to work with when incorporating with some other tooling. I can't confirm that this doesn't work, `System.out.println(Base64Utils.longFromBase64("DI"))` definitely logs "200".

Answer (score 0):

After reading the open source code. I managed to find how to encode.

> System.out.println("converted value=" +
> com.google.gwt.lang.LongLib.toBase64(200));
>
> converted value=DI